# Where to define scripts that deletes files older then 7 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

I need to write script that delete files older than 7 days in MVC .Net application. I'm going to use this code

```
   List<string> DeletePath = new List<string>();
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~\\TempFiles"));
        FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            DateTime CreationTime = file.CreationTime;
            double days = (DateTime.Now - CreationTime).TotalDays;
            if (days > 7)
            {
                string delFullPath = file.DirectoryName + "\\" + file.Name;
                DeletePath.Add(delFullPath);
            }
        }
        foreach (var f in DeletePath)
        {
            if (File.Exists(F))
            {
                File.Delete(F);
            }
        }
```

But i don't know where to define this and how to call. Do i need to create new Controller or something similar?

Comment: Personally, I would keep it outside of "MVC". It's really just a job that periodically (and relatively infrequently) runs - but is not tied to any of the normal application lifecycle.

Comment: YIKES! Sounds like a real strange requirement...you can do whatever you want in an application but answer these questions: 1) What happens if no one calls your MVC app for more than 7 days, who will trigger the "delete files" code? 2) Is your web app so secure that you are confident allowing it to change files on your disk?

Comment: BTW, that's not a script. That's a piece of a computer program.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your code in a static method and use hangfire

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => myCleanup.CleanupOldFiles(), Cron.Hourly)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to create a `window service` which will run in background on the server. Window services are the normal application which run automatically without any user event. Create a window service, then you can write the same code there wrapped in a `timer` `tick event`. There you can set the time when you want to execute this code.

Usually window service once deployed start executing your code every second. So you need to set the clock. With the Timer, you can execute your code as per your requirement, everyday at particular time, once in a week, once in a month or so on so forth.

Read more about window services [here...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx)

and let me know if you need code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Mvc is not the job for this. It's like asking how to install tires on a train so that it can drive up a private street.

In order for Mvc or any web application for that matter to do something, a request must come in from a client. If no request comes in, IIS does nothing and just "listens" for incoming connections. To do this the "correct" way, you have two options:

1. Create a [batch file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490869.aspx) or [Powershell script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835506(v=vs.85).aspx) or even a [C# console application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wc2kk78%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that deletes the files, then setup that batch file or script or program to run in [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).
2. If you need more logic to determine when the files should be deleted or you need customized schedules, then you should make a [Windows Service Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6(v=vs.110).aspx). You can make this in C# and you can pretty much have it do anything you want, so long as it doesn't need a GUI. If you do need a GUI, perhaps to configure the service, then you can make a separate WinForms or WPF application that can configure the service. There are several ways to implement GUI/Service communication. Some of the more popular ones are WCF communication, database configuration or even INI files.

Hope this helps!